# How to count the number of each type of room and total room?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

My query is like this :

```
SELECT name, room_type, room_number FROM table_room
```

The result is like this : 
[image]

I want to add a description like this :

```
Single Room : 3 Room
Double Room : 2 Room
Family Room : 1 Room
Total  : 6 room
```

additional information :

```
Single Room 1 : Tony
Single Room 2 : Eden
Single Room 3 : Christiano
Double Room 1 : Wayne and Christina
Double Room 2 : Ryan and Jose
Family Room 1 : David, Peter and Carlo
```

Total : 6 rooms, not 10 rooms

I have tried. But I am is still difficult.

Thank you.

---

To determine the number of rooms, it is not based on room type, but the room number

So based on the table above should result like this:

```
Single Room : 3 Room
Double Room : 2 Room
Family Room : 1 Room
Total  : 6 room
```

additional information :

```
Single Room 1 : Tony
Single Room 2 : Eden
Single Room 3 : Christiano
Double Room 1 : Wayne and Christina
Double Room 2 : Ryan and Jose
Family Room 1 : David, Peter and Carlo
```

Total : 6 rooms, not 10 rooms

Sorry if my question is less clear

Thank you very much

Comment: GROUP BY, do a UNION ALL with Total.

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: Guys. You can't guarantee the result order unless you include  `ORDER BY` Usually show the data in the order you want, but you cant depend on luck. Result can be alter if planner use a different index or parellism using multiple cpus.

Comment: You have received some good answers. To put closure to your question, please mark one of the questions as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired result with:

```
select room_type, count(*) as roomcount from test group by room_type
union all
select 'Total', count(*) as roomcount from test
```

Result:

```
+-------------+----------+
| room_type   | count(*) |
+-------------+----------+
| Double Room |        4 |
| Family Room |        3 |
| Single Room |        3 |
| Total       |       10 |
+-------------+----------+
```

You can retrieve this result with PHP and format it to your liking.

If you are using MySQL, you could even do something like this to get formatted output directly from the database like this:

```
select concat(
  room_type, ' : ', roomcount,
  case when roomcount < 2 then ' Room' else ' Rooms' end
) as outputstring
from (
select room_type, count(*) as roomcount from test group by room_type
union all
select 'Total', count(*) as roomcount from test
) sub_query
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+
| outputstring          |
+-----------------------+
| Double Room : 4 Rooms |
| Family Room : 3 Rooms |
| Single Room : 3 Rooms |
| Total : 10 Rooms      |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Try to check my answer below or my question above. I add additional information.

Comment: Where does the additional information reside? Do you have a table that tells who are in a Double room and who are in the Family room?

Comment: @mosestoh did you need further help? If you are satisfied with any of the answers provided here, could you please accept one and put closure to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `count` or `group by`

```
SELECT count(*) as total,room_type FROM table_room group by 
room_type
```

For total room :-

```
 SELECT count(*) as total_room FROM table_room
```

In singal query :-

```
SELECT count(*) as total,room_type,
(SELECT count(*) FROM table_room) as total_room FROM table_room group by 
room_type
```

Comment: Your script will give an error because you are neither using the name column without including it in the group by clause nor aggregating it.

Answer (score 0):

depend on your rdbms you can construct the string before return it

I include a column `order_id` so I can order and show `total` on last row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 1 order_id, room_type + ': ' +  Count(*) + ' Room' as desc
  FROM table_room
  GROUP BY room_type
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 order_id, 'Total : ' +  Count(*) + ' Room' as desc
  FROM table_room
)
ORDER BY order_id
```

**NOTE:** You can't guarantee the result order unless you include  `ORDER BY`

**NOTE 2:** The best way is you ask your query return only group total

```
| Double Room |        4 |
| Family Room |        3 |
| Single Room |        3 |
```

And calculate the total in the php UI. That way your query only have one type of data and doesn't have to worry about order

Answer (score 0):

```
select room_type, count(*) as roomcount from test group by room_type
UNION
select 'Total' as room_type , count(*) as roomcount from test
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc93f/4)

```
SELECT room_type, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table_room
GROUP BY room_type
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total' AS room_type, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table_room;
```